TV cartoon show name
I'm looking for a TV cartoon that I used to watch in the late 80's - early 90's.
What I can remember:

The main character was a teenager
It was set on space and distant
planets
The vehicles had like an eye on top of them, connected with a
green nerve

Any suggestions?

Jayce and the Wheeled Warriors?
The bad guys had vehicles with green appendages on top as can be seen from the intro:




You nailed it! Years searching for this...thanks
